# Add events to fullcalendar in meteor

Tags: meteor, fullcalendar

I try to use the fullcalendar package from Adam Shaw.

my html:

```
<head> 
<title>Calendar Test</title>
</head> 
<body>
<div id='head'>
    <h1>Calendar Test Meteor</h1>
</div>
<div id='calendar'>
    {{> schedule_assessments}}
</div>  
</body>

<template name="schedule_assessments">
    {{rendered}}
</template>
```

my js:

```
Template.schedule_assessments.rendered = function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },
    weekends: true, // will hide Saturdays and Sundays
    editable: true
});
}
```

I went through the documentation, but I couldn't find any meteor specific help.
For example: How can I add an event on double click? Is there already a Collection set for the events? If I click on a specific day, how can I detect this without knowing the name of this element?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The Event Handler are available for Clicking on specific normal day / event days.

Take a look at this [Clicking & Hovering](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/) functions are available

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

        alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
        alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
        alert('View: ' + view.name);

        // change the border color just for fun
        $(this).css('border-color', 'red');

}
```

You also take a look at the [eventRender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) function to trigger the Double click event for yourself.

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
        element.qtip({
            content: event.description
        });
}
```

Comment: this does not answer how to add events, though